# Unable to resolve the request in yii while calling new controller in module

Tags: php, yii

I created a module named CustomerOnBoarding. If I call an url like

> localhost/application_name/index.php?r=CustomerOnBoarding

it's calling its defaultcontroller and view. While on the other hand if i create my own controller and its view and call it by

> localhost/yii_learn/index.php/CustomerOnBoarding/Test/

then it's not working and throwing an error like

> Unable to resolve the request "CustomerOnBoarding/Test/index"

I have also changed urlmanager in config's main.php file 
like:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array('CustomerOnBoarding/Test/'=>'CustomerOnBoarding/Test/index'),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your new controller `NewController` action `new` like this:

`http://localhost/application_name/index.php?r=CustomerOnBoarding/NewController/new`

Comment: Should in need to do modification in any file ??As i did the same i created TestController.php file and its corresponding view .and then i just call url http://localhost/yii_learn/index.php/?r=CustomerOnBoarding/Test/